# how to compile Eigen to .so

Tags: c++, eigen

In the https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html,it said that Eigen is not necessary to use Cmake to install, and just to include the header file.But now I want to compile Eigen as a shared library to easily be linked in another shared library, someone can tell what to do?

How to compiler Eigen to a shared library&dll

Comment: Eigen is header-only.  There's nothing to compile to a shared library; just include the headers as needed.  Please clarify what your actual objective is.  Why do you think you want to compile Eigen to a shared library?

Comment: I want to use dlopen to link Eigen in my code，as it seems like the only way to seperate Eigen with my own code. As if  just including the header file in Eigen, the shared lib of my code which is compilered using NDK also mixed with Eigen. I just want the shared lib of my code is clear without any license debate.

Comment: If you want to avoid using Eigen inside your "main" program/library, you could write a separate library with a plain C-like interface which only internally uses Eigen. MPL does not even require you to distribute the source of that separate library (as far as I know, #NotALawyer).

Comment: You means I'd better write a C interface like Eigen's demo in the folder of Eigen/demos/mix_eigen_and_c ?

Answer (score 2):

The MPL is completely okay with you linking Eigen into your own code.
Some bits of Eigen are LGPL, which would pose a problem, but the Eigen [COPYING.README tells you how to strip LGPL code](https://github.com/PX4/eigen/blob/master/COPYING.README#L11-L18):

> If you want to guarantee that the Eigen code that you are #including
> is licensed under the MPL2 and possibly more permissive licenses (like
> BSD), `#define` this preprocessor symbol:   `EIGEN_MPL2_ONLY` For example,
> with most compilers, you could add this to your project CXXFLAGS:
> `-DEIGEN_MPL2_ONLY`
> This will cause a compilation error to be generated if you #include any code that is LGPL licensed.

Comment: Thks, but I even couldn't use MPL2 :(, can you have some solutions?

Comment: If your lawyers say you cannot even use MPL2 then Eigen is effectively dead to you. But please take a moment to read the MPL2 license text. It is *extremely* forgiving, especially if you are not making any modifications to it.

Comment: I have another question，the functions in Eigen seems like declares in header files not in *.c or *.cpp files, is it right?

Comment: As remarked in the first comment on your question: Eigen is a **header-only** library. That means it *must* be integrated with another translation unit, and you cannot simply create a library from it.